# Linking libpng with Borland C++

Tags: c++, windows, libpng, borland-c++

I made a program on Mac OS X using [OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) and dynamically linking [libpng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libpng). I'm now trying to port it to Windows. Whenever I try to compile and link my ported program in Borland it gives me this error and about 10 more that are the same, but with a different '_png_create_read_struct':

> Error: Unresolved external '_png_create_read_struct' reference from C:\PROGRAMMING\PNGTEST.OBJ

I assume it's because I have not properly set up libpng with Borland C++ 5.5.1 for [Win32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API). I've put png.h and pngconf.h into the include folder into C:\Borland\BCC55\Include, and I have put libpng12.dll.a, libpng13.a, libpng13.dll.a, libpng.a, libpng.dll.a, libpng12.def, libpng.def, libpng12.la, and libpng.la into C:\Borland\BCC55\Lib (there is probably no need for them all, but as a noob I have no idea which ones are needed and not).

Do I need to put a libpng.obj file in there too? And if so how would I make/get one? I have tried using makefile.bc32 to set up libpng, yet that gives me a missing separator error.

Here are my command-line options:

```
bcc32 -tW pngtest.cpp -lpng
```

I include png.h in my code. What am I doing wrong or is there an even better way to load images with alpha that doesn't need libpng, or even a better compiler to get for Windows?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off with the MinGW compiler than Borland.  Borland is not well supported any longer.

You could also download DevC++ and see if it has a libpng package in its addon mechanism.
DevC++ is an IDE that uses the MinGW C/C++ compiler.

That said, if you feel you must use BCC, you'll either have to
a) Build libpng with Borland.  This is the best solution if you're going to use borland.
b) Use, I think, Impdef to create an import library from libpng.dll.  You'll find impdef.exe or imp(something).exe in the borland bin directory.
Note that some libraries will not work with impdef as there is static code linked to the dll that causes it to fail without the proper runtime.

Comment: Ok lets see if that works, otherwise i'll go with MinGW. Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to down vote at least have the courtesy to say why.

Comment: @Mayerz: I remember it as impdef.exe from my Borland days, but...  I'm old and my memory could be wrong. :)

Comment: Haha ok! Don't worry I'm young and it's the same

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would not have "*polluted*" the BC55 installation with third-party libraries; it will make moving the project to other build environments much more difficult.  It would have been better to place them in a folder within your project.

Secondly do you *know* that the export library you are attempting to link is built for BC55?  The .a extension suggests a GNU library (Borland libraries conventionally use .lib extension), in which case it would not link with BC55 which uses a different object file format.  If this is the case you will need to rebuild the library as you attempted to do, so I suggest that you should really be asking a question about the problem you had with doing just that.  I wonder whether the makefile is written for Borland make or GNU make, since they have differing syntax?

The command line option `-lpng` might be correct for GCC (where it will link libpng.a), but is meaningless to BCC.  The `-l` [option](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC32,_the_C%2B%2B_Command-Line_Compiler) merely passes the text that follows to the linker.  The [linker command line](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/ILINK32.EXE,_the_Incremental_Linker), requires that the complete name be passed, and if no extension is provided, .lib is added implicitly.

Comment: Haha thanks, I really have no clue about most of this stuff. But the -tW thing actually makes it a windows gui program for me. When i compile other stuff with that same command line they just turn into the name of the cpp file with a .exe extension . I guess I'll keep trying to bulid libpng with borland and thank you very much for noticing the -lpng thing.

Comment: Regarding `-tW`, I misunderstood the meaning of "Specify target executable" in the option documentation. (I have now fixed the erroneous link in the post, but here it is again http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC32,_the_C%2B%2B_Command-Line_Compiler).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use coff2omf to convert the library. The DLL files are almost certainly in "Microsoft" [COFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF) format.

See *[COFF2OMF.EXE, the Import Library Conversion Tool](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/coff2omf_xml.html)*.